# Foi isso (o) que resolveu o problema

Tags: português-brasileiro, pronomes

Qual a forma correta ou qual a diferença entre as duas frases?

- Foi isso **o** que resolveu o problema
- Foi isso que resolveu o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ambas estão corretas e têm o mesmo significado.

Essa construção chama-se *frase clivada*, tem o objetivo de destacar um dado constituinte da frase e [constrói-se](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/idioma/tu-e-que-es/2118):

> verbo **ser** (+ **que** ou **o/aquilo/isso que**)

Um [exemplo](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/construcao-clivada/21944) (minha ênfase):

> Foi o vestido **o que/que** a Rita comprou na feira.

O pronome relativo "(o) que" é o [operador](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/que-operador-da-construcao-clivada/27862) da construção clivada e o "o" [teria apenas](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/oque-o-que-ou-o-que/)

> função de realce, podendo ser retirado da frase sem a alteração do seu sentido.

Comment: Estou de acordo no que diz respeito à frase em exemplo. Mas não tenho a certeza da função do ***o***; nomeadamente o artigo dizendo que o ***o*** simplesmente realça, fala apenas de ***que*** como pronome interrogativo ("que significa isso?" vs. "o que significa isso?", não fala de clivagem. Nota que a se alterarmos a ordem dos elementos na frase, não alteramos o significado, mas o ***o*** parece-me que passa a ser obrigatório: "Isso foi **o que** resolveu o problema" ou "**O que** resolveu o problema foi isso". Como disse, não tenho a certeza.

Comment: @Jacinto Eu tenho a mesma dúvida - inclusive hesitei em colocar essa parte, e considerei postar a pergunta "Quando 'o que' pode ser substituído por 'que'?". Relendo o link que você menciona, tenho mais certeza agora que ele se refere apenas ao "o que" *interrogativo*, e penso que vou eliminar a citação da resposta (antes vou esperar para ver se aparece mais algum feedback).